# Change Alternating Colors in Firemonkey TListView

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Dropping a tlistview onto a form and checking the property 'AlternatingColors' to true, by default it will show a grey background on every other item on the listview.

My question is does anyone now how to change this color to something else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the style of TlistView.

Right-click on listview, choose "Edit Custom Style" and in the structure panel there are two items: "itembackground" and "alternatinfitembackground".

You can change the colors from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when I do this, there doesn't appear to be anything in the structure panel. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried the "Edit Default Style" option? In Delphi Seattle there is a bug with the style manager and you can't see the structure of many elements but I don't know about XE8. If you do the same for a Listbox or a Tabcontrol is the structure panel populated?

Comment: Same with 'Edit Default Style' on the TListView. Also tried it with other components and they DO appear in the struture panel, must be a bug ??

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug. Try to download this file https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/TListView.style/_3b86f9b40ca0479d9c80fce61f3c8e00
It is the default style file. Then load it in your style manager. It is from D10.1 but not sure whether it works on DX8. But it is worth the try

Comment: @6String_Coder, did you solve this problem? Please could you give an example to do this at runtime?